# Airflow worker pods aren't starting on GKE cluster when just deploying airflow from the official helm. What do I do?

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a GKE cluster with 1 n1-standard-4 node in us-central1-c zone and then set it up to configure kubectl to point to the right cluster

`kubectl create namespace airflow` to create a namespace

`helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org` to add the helm chart

`helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -n airflow --debug` to deploy airflow

At this stage I expect that the airflow worker service and airflow-triggerer would have a status OK.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWHZT.png)

However looking at my services its not the case. Is there something I'm missing or something more I can check? I'm considering nuking my project and starting from scratch. This problem seems to be replicating on difference zones and node pools and I've tried a few times. I got git-sync to work because when I see the airflow webserver my dags show up but they don't run because there are no workers. I didn't change any of the executor types.

I've tried different combinations of nodepools and zones/regions

Comment: I decided to start from scratch, with a new project, enabled GKE, created a cluster, then did the same steps above and still get the same issue with Pods Pending. Does this workflow not work?

Comment: can you run a kubectl describe on the stuck pods and update your question please ?

Comment: Running `kubectl logs airflow-worker`, `kubectl logs airflow-triggerer`, `kubectl describe pod airflow-worker`, and `kubectl describe pod airflow-triggerer` and sharing the output would be helpful.

Comment: the problem was there was CrashLoopBackOff errors. I think maybe I had to just be patient with it to set up. I left it going on overnight and eventually the cluster became healthy.

Answer (score 0):

One thing may be that depending on the region or zone you are in it takes long to provision the nodes for the cluster. Eventually after leaving it overnight the cluster became healthy. I got a lot of different errors that weren't consistent but eventually it worked after some time.

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Quota Increase Request:

You can request an increase for the specific resource quota in the GCP console. This process may take a few hours to a few days and requires approval from GCP. Navigate to the GCP Quota page and request an increase for the SSD_TOTAL_GB resource. From what I've seen in most reviews, it's challenging to request a quota increase with a free account, and Google seems to monitor the service usage before deciding on the increase.

### 2) Choosing a Different Region:

I created the cluster in another region where there was more of the required resources available. However, when using this method, you might need to consider factors like network latency.

### 3) Cleaning Up Existing Resources:

By examining and releasing the SSD resources that are no longer in use or necessary, I was able to free up the required SSD storage space.

### solve) Additional Step:

I also went to IAM > Quotas, where I removed the unnecessary SSD resources and then successfully created the cluster.

### referecne

- https://mjs1995.tistory.com/298

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).